# Is there a way to rotate view by 180 or 90 degrees with 1 command?

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, shortcut

Most of the time I use the "hold alt + drag middle mouse button in a direction" to rotate the view. There are often times when I want to see the top or bottom view and then rotate the top/bottom view by 180 degrees along the Z axis.

I know I can rotate the view 180 degrees by pressing the Numpad_4 or Numpad_6 keys twelve times but I rather have a shortcut I can press once or ideally, a way to do it with the middle mouse drag gestures since using the numpad is a bit cumbersome when my right hand mostly sits on the mouse.

Comment: You can do it with three, by pressing `4`, `9`, `6` on the Numpad from top/bottom view. Its a bit of a hack but it works. It takes you off orthographic mode, though.

Comment: I see, so it really is 4, 9, 6, 5. Thanks, that's definitely an improvement from 12 presses. Still hoping someone knows an instant way to do it though.

Comment: @impresso It only takes you out of orthographic if you have 'Auto Perspective' enabled in the preferences.

Comment: @RayMairlot OH I didn't know that! Autoperspective off with the setting to rotate by 90 degress is great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1

You can go into the reverse of an orthographic view (i.e. the view is rotated by 180 degrees) by adding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the numpad number. For example <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> goes into *front* view but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> goes into *back* view. This works for <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>.

So you can either press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to go into front view and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to reverse that view or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to go directly into that view.

#### Method 2

It is currently taking you 12 presses to rotate the view using the number pad keys because the 'Rotation Angle' is set to 15 (degrees). Luckily, there is a user preference option to set this to a custom angle (the maximum value it can be set to is 90 degrees).

In 2.8 you can go to *Edit> Preferences> Navigation> Orbit & Pan* and change the 'Rotation Angle' from there:

[image]

Comment: awesome! that's two taps and its the same key, dont think it gets any better than that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there might be a way to rotating by 90 degrees with the mouse instead?